# "UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8" trying to do "python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django

I've literally just started some Django lessons because I looked up the options I have and pretty sure it's the best way to complete an internship programming challenge a company assigned to me. The page I ran "django-admin startproject mysite" was "projetoEstados", then I went into mysite through prompt and tryied to run "python manage.py runserver", to be able to properly access 127.0.0.1:8000 and actually start the project, that's when I got the problem.

I looked up on a few foruns, including StackOverflow, but couldn't find someone with the exact same problem I'm having, most people kinda knew where the problem was, I'm literally 1 hour into Django, so yes, I'm the most beginner someone could be, so I have no clue on where to go with that error message.

So, the exact error I'm getting is in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMKuj.jpg). This print is unfortunately as specific as i can be, so please someone help me lol.

I was obviously expecting no error message, maybe some unapplied migrations, but that's it. Don't know how obvious this information will be, but I can't access 127.0.0.1:8000 to access Django development server with that error happening.

Comment: Can you please check what is the hostname of your system? Type `hostname` on a command prompt and let us know the result.

Comment: it just returns my name

Comment: Does your computer name of the hosts DNS name contain special characters? An `ã` to be more precise?

Comment: it actually does, is that really it?

Comment: You will have to change the computer name to a valid DNS name.  `a-z`, `0-9` and `-` only.

Comment: thank you so much, guys, pretty random issue I was having lol

Answer (score 0):

The computer name contained special character. It had to be changed to a valid DNS hostname.